# How to convert winrt::hstring to int in C++ Winui application?

Tags: c++, winrt-xaml, winui-3

I have used the template called `Blank App, Package (Winui 3 in desktop)` inside Visual Studio. I want to make a really simple function which add 2 value together. This is what the application looks like.

[image]

This is the XAML code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="Box1" PlaceholderText="First number"></TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="Box2" PlaceholderText="Second number"></TextBox>

    <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click">Calculate</Button>
    <TextBlock x:Name="answer"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

This is the code in C#.

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int number1 = Convert.ToInt32(Box1.Text);
    int number2 = Convert.ToInt32(Box2.Text);
    int sum = number1 + number2;
    answer.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

Everything is good in C# but when I moved to C++. I got some type error which winrt::hstring cannot be convert to int. Below is the C++ code

```
This code got problem
void MainWindow::myButton_Click(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
{
    int number1 = stoi(Box1().Text());
    int number2 = stoi(Box2().Text());
    int sum = number1 + number2;
    answer().Text(L"");
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/strings

Comment: `stoi` takes a `std::string` but you don't have a `std::string`. Best bet is probably `wcstol` and use the `hstring::c_str()` method to get a `const wchar_t *` that you can pass to `wcstol`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a method.

```
std::string number_1 = winrt::to_string(Box1().Text());
std::string number_2 = winrt::to_string(Box2().Text());

int number1 = stoi(number_1);
int number2 = stoi(number_2);
int sum = number1 + number2;
winrt::hstring h_string_sum = winrt::to_hstring(sum);

answer().Text(h_string_sum);
```